# Get married: act vs ceremony

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, style-manuals

> You can use *marriage* to refer to the ***act*** of **getting
> married**, *Her family did not approve of her **marriage** to David*.
>
> You don't usually use *marriage* to refer to the ***ceremony*** in
> which two people **get married**. Use *wedding*.
>
> [Marriage | WordReference.com](https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/marriage)

I don't understand the purported difference in meaning between the **act** and the **ceremony** of *getting married.*

Maybe using *wedding* here would be ambiguous, with a possible interpretation "they didn't like the wedding planner's whole organization"?

Comment: Probably not of 'answer' status: The [usually _wedding_] _ceremony_ is the formulaic/ritualistic, often lengthy and involving a religious service, procedure. The [_marriage_]  _act_ (included in the above where the above takes place, though I suppose in certain cases only a brief transaction takes place) is the saying of the necessary elements by bride and groom and the speech act by one in authority conferring married status upon them. Note also that 'marriage' is additionally used to refer to the non-single state.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Synonymous with _...of her **marrying** (to?) David_ ? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marrying#English

Comment: @GJC In that context I think it's more common to say "marrying" if it's a potential or upcoming marriage, "marriage" if they're already married, but it's not rigid.

Comment: "I don't understand the purported [??] difference in meaning between the act and the ceremony of getting married". The act of getting married and the ceremony of getting married are the same thing. That person should have written: the fact of getting married and not the act.

Comment: It's like the difference between a death and a funeral, except people usually get married at a wedding rather than shortly beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

According to Oxford [Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/marriage?q=marriage), *marriage* clearly *can* be used to refer to the ceremony.

**marriage** [noun] ...

(3) [countable] the ceremony in which two people marry each other

> Their marriage took place in a local church.

Though OALD adds the caveat:

> *Wedding* is more common in this meaning.

The following provides a good example where 'wedding' and 'marriage' are non-interchangeable:

- *Their marriage was a disaster* implies that the couple were not happy in their life together and are probably now separated or divorced.

On the other hand,

- *Their wedding was a disaster* implies that something happened during the wedding and that the ceremony did not go smoothly. The couple can go on to have a long and happy marriage even after a disastrous wedding.

Comment: **MARRY** https://www.oed.com/oed2/00141163, **MARRIED** https://www.oed.com/oed2/00141128  (and _wed_ https://www.oed.com/oed2/00282179), **wedding** https://www.oed.com/oed2/00282193.

Comment: @GJC You keep posting entries from the OED. So, why do you need anyone here? Kazi has demonstrated very well the way the two are not interchangeable. A wedding is a ceremony; a marriage usually refers to the state of being married. And wed is no longer used in modern speech.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are actually two (related) questions here:

Q1. Since marriage can refer to the state or the act, why is it not usually used to refer to the act and why is "wedding" preferred.

I think it is just a loose convention or fashion.

Also, perhaps, in common usage, the focus of "wedding" may be of a celebration with guests, a formal meal, etc. so is a bit wider in meaning than the literal wed-ing (i.e., marriage ceremony) which is at its core.

Q2. Given that (for whatever reason) it is not so common to refer to the act as "marriage" how come "Her family did not approve of her marriage to David" is a common usage?

The answer here is that the disapproval is to the entering into the continuing state of marriage with David. Obviously entering into the state of marriage involves the act of marriage but the emphasis is on ending up in the state of marriage with David rather than the act which got the bride into that continuing state.

An analogy may help. If someone says that they disapprove of the exit of US troops from Afghanistan, they might mean (1) they think that US troops should have stayed or (2) they think the way the exit was done was chaotic. Of course, they might think both (1) and (2) but there is a distinct difference in emphasis between (1) and (2).